# How to easily Debug Layout Xml Warning/Error?

Tags: xml, debugging, magento, xdebug

I got stuck on this error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 46: parser error : Comment not terminated  in */lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

and

```
Entity: line 46: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found  in */lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

It is clear that there is an issue in some Xml file, but really not easy for me to find out the needle in the big haystack :)

Any good practice for that? 
If possible I would like to find a good practice that involves use Xdebug, or some log.

It happens a lot of time in Magento to do some miss spelling.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you can take a look at this article [Dealing with XML errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php).

This warning is related to some config.xml error, so a possible workaround to find out the exact file is to mod. the /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php class.

You should modify `Varien_Simplexml_Config::loadString()` method:

```php
public function loadString($string)
{
    if (is_string($string)) {
        // Enable internal errors
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
        if (false === $xml) {
            // Put breakpoint here
            $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        }
        if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
            $this->_xml = $xml;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
    }
    return false;
}
```

In case the error is related to some Layout file ( Update.php line 444 warning )

You should modify `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()` method in a similar way:

```php
public function getFileLayoutUpdatesXml($area, $package, $theme, $storeId = null)
{
    if (null === $storeId) {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    }
    /* @var $design Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package */
    $design = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package');
    $layoutXml = null;
    $elementClass = $this->getElementClass();
    $updatesRoot = Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode($area.'/layout/updates');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_layout_update_updates_get_after', array('updates' => $updatesRoot));
    $updateFiles = array();
    foreach ($updatesRoot->children() as $updateNode) {
        if ($updateNode->file) {
            $module = $updateNode->getAttribute('module');
            if ($module && Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('advanced/modules_disable_output/' . $module, $storeId)) {
                continue;
            }
            $updateFiles[] = (string)$updateNode->file;
        }
    }
    // custom local layout updates file - load always last
    $updateFiles[] = 'local.xml';
    $layoutStr = '';
    foreach ($updateFiles as $file) {
        $filename = $design->getLayoutFilename($file, array(
            '_area'    => $area,
            '_package' => $package,
            '_theme'   => $theme
        ));
        if (!is_readable($filename)) {
            continue;
        }
        $fileStr = file_get_contents($filename);
        $fileStr = str_replace($this->_subst['from'], $this->_subst['to'], $fileStr);   


        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $fileXml = simplexml_load_string($fileStr, $elementClass);


        if (false === $fileXml) {
            // Put breakpoint here
            $errors = libxml_get_errors();
            $err = array($filename, $errors);
            // error detail and file name will be printed
            Zend_Debug::dump($err);
            die();
        }



        if (!$fileXml instanceof SimpleXMLElement) {
            continue;
        }
        $layoutStr .= $fileXml->innerXml();
    }
    $layoutXml = simplexml_load_string('<layouts>'.$layoutStr.'</layouts>', $elementClass);
    return $layoutXml;
}
```

Now just reload the page a read the error info.

Comment: There is nothing special related to Magento architecture, it is just XML file :)

Comment: Are you aware of how many xml are there in magento and how many times this line of code is triggered every time you load a page ?

Comment: Of course I know this. But those approach will take into account xml strings with errors only. You should make a call to `libxml_get_errors()` only if there is a problem with xml string loading.

Comment: ok can you add precise instruction ? I should add some code some where ?

Comment: thank you this is a part of the solution, I can figure out the module name but not the current file processed

Comment: In debug trace you should see everything. Take a look at `Varien_Simplexml_Config->loadFile()` - there is variable $filePath.

Comment: Thank you I have edited you answer in order to make it more general and Xdebug independent ( and also get filename )

Answer (score 4):

Well, after a good search, if the `$string` is all the CML merged, you have almost not chance to find what tag is bad closed.

I found a way to do it, in the class /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php you have to modify the next method:

```php
public function loadFile($filePath)
{
    if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
        //throw new Exception('Can not read xml file '.$filePath);
        return false;
    }

    $fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);
    $fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);
    //add this try catch
    try{
        $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump("The error: " . $e->getMessage());
        var_dump("The bad file" . $filePath);
    }

    return $this->loadString($fileData, $this->_elementClass);
}
```

In this way we now can see what file has a bad tag.

Answer (score 2):

If your test environment is Linux, you can also use XMLLint `xmllint` to check the layout xml file for inconsistencies after you've made changes to it. Checking before implementation discovers a multitude of sins and prevents having errors thrown.

Comment: I've tried this several times. And it's very effective in fixing XML issues in Magento. This is the command you will use in the terminal
`for file in `find . -name "*.xml"`; do xmllint --noout $file; done`

Answer (score 2):

Edit file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php and search for function "getFileLayoutUpdatesXml".

Add:

```
Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));
```

aproximately at line 442, before:

```
$fileStr = file_get_contents($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve that case, in same file */lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line#489

Print path of loaded XML file put `Zend_Debug::dump($filePath);` after `$fileData = $this->processFileData($fileData);`

and overwrite function loadString($string)

---

```php
if (is_string($string)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
    if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
        $this->_xml = $xml;
        return true;
    }
} else {
    Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
}
return false;
```

Replace with

```php
if (is_string($string)) {
    // Enable internal errors
    //Mage::log($string);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);

    if (false === $xml) {
        // Put breakpoint here
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        $err = array($errors);
        // error detail and file name will be printed
        Zend_Debug::dump($string);;
        Zend_Debug::dump($err);
        die();
    }
    if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
        $this->_xml = $xml;
        return true;
    }
} else {
    Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
}
return false;
```

And this will print the path and error where this create problem.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
*/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

go and add a debug line and echo out the xml it tries to load and see what is wrong with this string.

Comment: Your solution is the one I always use I can say it is not very efficient:
the problem is that magento load a lot of xml and so the debug line will triggered thousand of times ...
I have tried adding a `try{} catch{}` but because it is a warning ...