# Cannot send headers; headers already sent

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Hello everyone I am getting an error that I cannot seem to fix.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:93:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/exowear/public_html/app/Mage.php, line 766";i:1;s:1013:"#0 /home/exowear/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/exowear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /home/exowear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /home/exowear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /home/exowear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/exowear/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/exowear/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/exowear/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/index.php";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I am trying to set it up on  the live domain, but I keep running into this. It is working fine on my test server. http://mytempsite.net/sin but when I bring it over to http://vegassinexoticwear.com I get this error.

#### What I Tried

- I backed up the entire directory on my temp site and brought it over to the new server using SSH. Then I exported the DB and Imported it into the new DB. Changes the URL in the core_config_data table. Cleared the cache and even checked permissions.
- I installed a new copy of magento and brought over the app, skin, and media folders all separately. Before bringing it over there were no errors but once I brought the app folder over I got this error again.

Why does it work on one server and not on the other server?

**EDITED/ ADDITIONAL DETAILS**
this is the error I am not getting when trying to go to the site.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 4: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /home/exowear/public_html/sin/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/exowear/p...', 510, Array)
#1 /home/exowear/public_html/sin/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('loadString('loadFile('/home/exowear/p...')
#4 /home/exowear/public_html/sin/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(315): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_loadDeclaredModules()
#5 /home/exowear/public_html/sin/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModules()
#6 /home/exowear/public_html/sin/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#7 /home/exowear/public_html/sin/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /home/exowear/public_html/sin/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

When I go look at Config.php line 510 this is what is there

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);
```

The whole function is this

```
 */
public function loadString($string)
{
    if (is_string($string)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);

        if ($xml instanceof Varien_Simplexml_Element) {
            $this->_xml = $xml;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        Mage::logException(new Exception('"$string" parameter for simplexml_load_string is not a string'));
    }
    return false;
}
```

My local.xml file was saved making sure BOM was unchecked in DW CS6

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--
 /**
  * Magento
  *
  * NOTICE OF LICENSE ......
  -->
 <config>
     <global>
         <install>
             <date><![CDATA[Mon, 10 Jun 2013 16:34:40 +0000]]></date>
         </install>
         <crypt>
             <key><![CDATA[9a38bb0fba550a5d295b3789fe2dafee]]></key>
         </crypt>
         <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
         <resources>
             <db>
                 <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
             </db>
             <default_setup>
                 <connection>
                     <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                     <username><![CDATA[usernamehere]]></username>
                     <password><![CDATA[passwordhere]]></password>
                     <dbname><![CDATA[dbnamehere]]></dbname>
                     <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                     <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                     <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                     <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                     <active>1</active>
                 </connection>
             </default_setup>
         </resources>
         <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
     </global>
     <admin>
         <routers>
             <adminhtml>
                 <args>
                     <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                 </args>
             </adminhtml>
         </routers>
     </admin>
 </config>
```

Comment: I mostly get these errors when I have an echo / var_dump from debugging left over in my code. try checking that first

Answer (score 2):

Let's try to debug together.
In Mage.php file line 766

```
$localConfigFile = $etcDir . DS . 'local.xml';

    if (is_readable($localConfigFile)) {
        $localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
            self::$_isInstalled = true;
        }
    }
```

So what Magento tries to do here is to load `app/etc/local.xml`

My guess would be that when you change your DB name/username/password you saved the file incorrectly (some editors add BOM signature). The local.xml file should be saved UTF8 without BOM option.

Comment: Your correct I actually just fixed my db name i was missing an "]" at the end.

Comment: but now I get this error 

Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 4: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /home/exowear/public_html/sin/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Comment: how would the syntax change when all i did was transfer from one server to the other and change values?

Comment: You could forget to open or close a tag

Comment: try to reload this file and change fields again and also save it without BOM

Comment: Tried that and that did not work. I am gonna update my question with a new error

Comment: Magento caches this configfile. Did you clear the cache? If you use filecache just empty `var/cache` in your magento folder.

Comment: I would recommend you to start another topic as it's a different error. To debug it read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152232/how-to-easily-debug-layout-xml-warning-error

Answer (score 1):

many time this problem occuer from file permission

so please set proper file permission for more info

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/cache_is_not_writable

Answer (score 0):

enable error reporting and try to create log file

Mage::log('Cannot send headers; headers already sent in ' . $file . ', line ' . $line);

Comment: Can you tell me where to put this?

Answer (score 0):

Also one more reason of header already sent

In index.php added any echo then show error and in var/reports showing header already sent error

please check index.php if added any echo then remove it

Comment: Did you read the entire post to see that I updated it and am getting a different error now?

Comment: i read your post

now you face "Warning: simplexml_load_string"

this problem occer 
1. file permission like cache etc directory
2. missing any xml node like

<store
 <config/>
</stores>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem for that error is only "]" for current issue. Try to check your new host detail, user name and password. Also, correct way to add.

Answer (score 0):

There has been an error processing your request

Cannot send headers; headers already sent in `/var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/Mage.php, line 767`:

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/leaveasy.com/Leaveasy/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}

Error log record number: 724004798
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem, and I was able to fix it myself. I reviewed my local.xml, and found out an extra character å character, because I accidentally entered and saved it when I pressed OPTION + A in my keyboard, instead of CONTROL + A. :)

Answer (score 0):

this can happen for several reasons. To find out wich of those reason is the one affecting you, follow these instructions:

Instead of opening your page in the browser, run in the commandline:

```
curl http://yourpage.com/
```

you will get the error and/or data that is being written before the headers can be send.

Example, I got this:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/var/log/system.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/app/Mage.php</b> on line <b>832</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  chmod(): Permission denied in <b>/var/www/html/app/Mage.php</b> on line <b>833</b><br />
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = 'http://bluepowershop.localhost/errors/report.php?id=629963827323&skin=default';</script>
```

that means I have to setup my permissions for var/log files to be writtable.